# Schedule function call in React (Node as backend) to perform exactly at day and time which is specified in a database

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I want to show the user exactly to the second when he can have access to a given page, othervise it will be blocked. Lets say that I receive specific date and time from the server.

I guess I could use setTimeout function but I'm sure its a bad idea.
I can use a scheduler like node cron in backend but I'd need to send a message to frontend somehow after given time has passed.

Are webSockets an option? Or is there easier way?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to show the user exactly to the second when he can have access to a given page

For such accuracy, indeed the WebSocket communication is the way to go. This protocol is widely used on the web for push notification in email/social services like Gmail, Facebook etc.

Regarding the backend, I would suggest you to use a more scalable approach. You could use [Bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull) to create a scheduling service. Bull uses Redis as a store and can operate with multiple processors(Node Processes), ensuring that each task is processed only by one processor. With one word it abstracts away the complexities which arise in distributed systems.